# Java dynamic column headers

Tags: java, dynamic, header

I have a requirement where I need to make few Java calls and retrieve necessary values. These are all strings. I need to write this to a console with comma separated values. Like below:

```
3,Till,,Till,Weiss,,
3,ugilad,,ugilad,ugilad,,
3,admintest,,admin,test,abc@sample.com,
```

Expected should be:

```
userid,firstname,lastname,email
3,Till,,Till,Weiss,,
3,ugilad,,ugilad,ugilad,,
3,admintest,,admin,test,abc@sample.com,
```

Now I need to add columns to these values. Say: userId, firstName, lastName like this. How can I achieve this dynamically using Java code? Here is the code that I wrote:

```
                if (usersList.totalCount != 0 && usersList.totalCount >= 1) {
                System.out.println("usersList.totalCount ----->"
                        + usersList.totalCount);
                for (KalturaUser user : usersList.objects) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.id != null) {
                            String userRole = getUserRole(user.id);
                            String cnum = getUserUniqueId(user.email);
                            // if (userRole != null) {
                            // if (userRole.equals("adminRole")
                            // || userRole
                            // .equals("privateOnlyRole")) {
                            // sb1.append(action);

                            if (user.id != null) {
                                sb.append(user.id);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                            }
                            String action = "1";

                            if (cnum != null) {
                                if (userRole == null) {
                                    action = "3";
                                }
                            } else {
                                action = "3";
                            }
                            if (action != null) {
                                sb1.append(action);
                            }
                            if (cnum != null) {
                                sb1.append(",").append(cnum);
                            } else {
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.id);
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            if (user.firstName != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(user.firstName);
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.firstName);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }
                            if (user.lastName != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(user.lastName);
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.lastName);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }
                            if (userRole != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(userRole);
                                // sb1.append(",").append(userRole);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                // action = "3";
                                // sb1.append(action);
                            }
                            // sb1.append("1");
                            if (user.email != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(user.email);
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.email);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            if (userRole != null) {
                                sb1.append(",").append(userRole);
                            } else {
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            // sb1.append("1");

                            if (user.partnerData != null) {
                                if (user.partnerData.startsWith("pw")
                                        && user.partnerData.length() == 43) {
                                    sb.append(",");
                                }
                                if (user.partnerData.length() > 43) {
                                    String partnerData = user.partnerData
                                            .substring(44);
                                    sb.append(",").append(partnerData);
                                }
                                if (!user.partnerData.startsWith("pw")) {
                                    sb.append(",").append(user.partnerData);
                                }
                            }
                            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                            sb1.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // System.out.println(sb);
            System.out.println(sb1);
```

Comment: Any example of the expected output ?

Comment: What column? Do you want to print it in a tabular form in console?

Comment: @ Jean- UserID, FirstName, LastName and then from next line onwards the values for those respective columns like above sample output. I am already getting the values, but how to add headers is the problem.

Comment: @ Syam - Headers in First row like userid,firstname,lastname and then from next line the values of those headers with comma separated values: 1,fname,lastname like this

Comment: For that you could just print `userid,firstname,lastname,email` before the for loop right?

Comment: @Syam - I can do that. But need to change the column names based on conditions. So I thought it will be good to write this information into csv file and then export.

Comment: Yeah. Got it. If the amount of data is less then the simplest option is to collect all the string to a list and then build the header and print all at once.  If its huge you could flush all to a file and later modify the file with the new  header. I could give you a sample for these approach. If you want to show it in console you may have to consider libs like charva or jcurses.

Comment: @Syam - Thank you so much for quick responses. As of now I have solved my problem appending statically. But I want to change going forward. As you said, if you could give me sample, it will be helpful. Thanks once again for assisting me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you are appending everything to a string buffer(sb) and printing it at once. So in between the loop you could create a string `header` and assign value based on condition. And outside the loop first print header and then print the buffer. That would be the simplest soultion. However if the amount of data is buge it would be better to use a file. Write everything to a file, construct the header and then after the loop print the header and then print the file. A sample with dummy logic and classes

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class UserList {
    public int totalCount;
    public List<KalturaUser> objects;

    public UserList(List<KalturaUser> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
        this.totalCount = (objects != null) ? objects.size() : 0;
    }
}

class KalturaUser {
    public String id;
    public String email;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String partnerData;

    public KalturaUser(String id, String email, String firstName,
            String lastName, String partnerData) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.partnerData = partnerData;
    }
}

public class DynamicHeader {

    private static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UserList usersList = init();
        RandomAccessFile csv = new RandomAccessFile("temp.csv","rw");
        csv.setLength(0); //Clears the file
        String header = "";
        if (usersList.totalCount >= 1) {
            for (KalturaUser user : usersList.objects) {
                if (user != null && user.id != null) {
                    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String userRole = getUserRole(user.id);
                    String cnum = getUserUniqueId(user.email);
                    row.add(getNullSafeValue(user.id));
                    String action = "1";
                    if (cnum == null || userRole == null) {
                        action = "3";
                    }
                    row.add(action);
                    if (cnum != null) {
                        row.add(cnum);
                        header = "uniqueid,firstname,lastname,email";
                    } else {
                        row.add(user.id);
                        header = "userid,firstname,lastname,email";
                    }
                    row.add(getNullSafeValue(user.firstName));
                    row.add(getNullSafeValue(user.lastName));
                    row.add(getNullSafeValue(userRole));
                    row.add(getNullSafeValue(user.email));
                    if (user.partnerData != null) {
                        if (user.partnerData.startsWith("pw")) {
                            if (user.partnerData.length() == 43) {
                                row.add("");
                            } else if (user.partnerData.length() > 43) {
                                row.add(user.partnerData.substring(44));
                            }
                        } else {
                            row.add(user.partnerData);
                        }
                    }
                    csv.write(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", ",").getBytes());
                    csv.write(NEW_LINE.getBytes());
                }
            }
        }
        csv.seek(0);
        System.out.println(header);
        String data;
        while((data = csv.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        csv.close();
    }

    private static UserList init() {
        List<KalturaUser> userObjs = new ArrayList<KalturaUser>();
        userObjs.add(new KalturaUser("1", null, "Till", "Till", "Weiss"));
        userObjs.add(new KalturaUser("2", null, "ugilad", "ugilad", "ugilad"));
        userObjs.add(new KalturaUser("3", "abc@sample.com", "admin", "test", "admintest"));
        return new UserList(userObjs);
    }

    private static String getNullSafeValue(String str) {
        return (str != null) ? str : "";
    }

    private static String getUserUniqueId(String email) {
        return (email != null) ? email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@")) : null; //Replace with proper logic
    }

    private static String getUserRole(String id) {
        return ("2".equals(id)) ?  "Role 2" : null; //Replace with proper logic
    }

}
```

Apart from this you could do some clean ups in your code like below. Also insteaded of constructing string you could just add it to a list. The toString of list gives you a comma separated value.

```
(usersList.totalCount != 0 && usersList.totalCount >= 1)
```

could be reduced to `(usersList.totalCount > 0)`

```
if (user != null) {  
    if (user.id != null) {}
}
```

If you dont have to do anything specific when `(user != null)` then, this could be combined to

```
if (user != null && user.id != null) {}
```

And

```
if (cnum != null) {
    if (userRole == null) {
        action = "3";
    }
} else {
    action = "3";
}
```

This could be reduced to

```
if (cnum == null || userRole == null) {
    action = "3";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me code. I need to implement this. Will let u know if this goes fine.